# Range Definition in DL

Tags: owl, description-logic

We define the range of a property as *⊤ ⊑ ∀ r.C* in DL.

I do not understand the idea behind this definition. 
Why is *T* (i.e. owl:Thing) defined as subclass of  *∀ r.C*? What does that mean? 
Is there any case where *T* is in fact a smaller set than  ∀ r.C? Why don't we use *⊤ ≡ ∀ r.C*?

Imagine I have a role: *eats*; whose range is my *Food* class. What would *⊤ ⊑ ∀ eats.Food* mean, in plain natural language?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

⊤ ⊑ ∀*r*.*C* means that everything that has a relation *r* with something must have this relation with an instance of *C*. ∀*r*.*C* represents the class of things such that, when they have a relation *r* with something, then this relation is with an instance of *C*. For instance, ∀`hasParent`.`Person` represents the things that have people as parents. There may also be things that have parents that are not people, such as cats and dogs. By making the class a superclass of ⊤, you ensure that *everything* that has the relation has it with a member of *C*. Thus, you guarantee that the range of the relation is *C*.

Now, we do not write ⊤ ≡ ∀*r*.*C* because the notation *X* ≡ *Y* is a shortcut for {*X* ⊑ *Y*, *Y* ⊑ *X*} and for any concept *X*, it is always true that *X* ⊑ ⊤. So, writing ⊤ ≡ ∀*r*.*C* would be redundent.

Your example with `eats` and `Food` is a good example. Anything that eats something, eats food. Or, said differently, in a way closer to the form of the axiom: "whenever something has a relation `eats` with something, then the relation is with an element of the `Food` class. Of course, in natural language, we do not express this statement in this way, as it sounds very convoluted.

Note that an equivalent way of representing range is: ∃*r*<sup>–</sup>.⊤ ⊑ *C*, where *r*<sup>–</sup> is the inverse role of *r*.